# MVC Routing - Dynamic url name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC application where we have different links in my Home page. Each link triggers the same action in a Controller. I need to show a different name for the controller dynamically based on the link the users are clicking. Please let me know how can we achieve this.

Ex: 
Existing: `http://myapp.com/mycontroller/myaction`

What I need:

`http://myapp.com/mycontroller1/myaction`

`http://myapp.com/mycontroller2/myaction`

`http://myapp.com/mycontroller3/myaction`

PS: mycontroller1, mycontroller2, mycontroller3 are not actual controllers

Comment: You can do by passing a parameter to your controller action and then do if checks on params. finally based on param you can return required action. I also would like to see your whole code so that i can answer in a better way. :)

Comment: Hi Ajay,  Suppose I have an Index method in a controller named TestController then my URL will be http://myapp.com/Test/Index . But in my Index method I will have a session variable with which I need to change the name of the Controller in the URL to a different name. For example http://myapp.com/Test1/Index. Please note that the Test1 is just a name but the actual controller is Test only.

Comment: so basically you want to route to that controller path  (myapp.com/Test1/Index) ...am i right??

Comment: No. Actually i need a different name for the controller in the URL. For an Index action in a TestController i need different name in the URL for the controller dynamically. in the URL i need  http://myapp.com/{dynamic name}/Index.  where i should be able to provide the dynamic name based on a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

If in RouteConfig RegisterRoutes you add

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

In the action you can use

```
[Route("mycontroller1/myaction")]
[Route("mycontroller2/myaction)]
[Route("mycontroller3/myaction)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

I think is the simple way

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain how can I choose the route within the Index action based on  a session variable value.

Answer (score 0):

> You can call following urls on required links which will pass unique id to the
>   same controller method and based on that method, view will be
>   dynamically routed to required path..

**Trigger/Event:**

```
 Link-1 http://myapp.com/mycontroller/myaction?id=1
 Link-2 http://myapp.com/mycontroller/myaction?id=2
 Link-3 http://myapp.com/mycontroller/myaction?id=3
```

**C# code**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  if(id==1)
  {
    return View ("mycontroller1/myaction");
  }
  else if(id==2)
  {
    return View ("mycontroller2/myaction");
  }
  else if(id==3)
  {
    return View ("mycontroller3/myaction");
  }
  return View();
}
```

Happy coding!!